# Simple Eclipse library project to jar

Tags: android, eclipse

I use this Library project: https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator
In order to make it work in my project, I've created a new project based on the source code provided by the git and added a Reference to it in my Final project. Everything works fine. I use it in my Final project like:

```
 <com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
        android:id="@+id/indicator"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

I'd like to avoid this Library project reference and use a simple jar in my Final project. I've taken the jar generated in my library project and added in Final project in Java Build Path.
When I run it I get an error:

```
12-09 10:57:34.714: E/AndroidRuntime(10492): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.test/com.test.SettingsActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
```

Is it possible to achieve what I want ?

Comment: You add Library project in Your Project?

Comment: Yes I've added it, but I'd prefer to add only a jar file because it's easier to reuse it or send project source code only. This is what the question is all about....

Comment: So Export Library Project as a Jar file and Import in your prohject

Comment: How can I make this export ? I just took the library.jar file from my Library's Project bin folder and added in my Final project in Java Build Path. Is something wrong with this procedure ? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current version (15.0.1) of the Android Developer Tools do not allow projects which contain resources (e.g., layouts, custom attributes, etc.) to be bundled as a simple `.jar`.

As per [the library project documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects):

> However, a library project differs from an standard Android application project in that you cannot compile it directly to its own .apk and run it on an Android device. Similarly, you cannot export the library project to a self-contained JAR file, as you would do for a true library. Instead, you must compile the library indirectly, by referencing the library in the dependent application and building that application.

ADT currently attaches a `.jar` of library projects in Eclipse for linking purposes to work around the previously temperamental purely project references. This does not have any of the resources bundled with it, however.

The [download page](http://tools.android.com/download) of the ADT Tools website does not indicate that support for this will be making it in to ADT 16 either (as of ADT 16 preview 2). The current rumor is that this will make its way into version 17 of the tools which is still a good ways off. I cannot cite this as it's mainly hear-say from Twitter and the Android developer chat room.

For now, you're stuck using it as a library project.

Trust me, no one wants to bundle these projects as `.jar`s more than I do :)

Comment: @Jake: could you point us to your source of info? At http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects I found the following "Note: You need SDK Tools r14 or newer to use the new library project feature that generates each library project into its own JAR file." But this could mean anything. Release notes for SDK Tools, Revision 14 (October 2011) say nothing about it except: "Changed how library projects are built."

Comment: Added some citations and clarifications as best I could. I was unable to locate the original bug on b.android.com for this feature.

Answer (score 1):

I have created TitlePageIndicator dinamically and exception not throws:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

    ViewPager pager = new ViewPager(this);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    TitlePageIndicator indicator = new TitlePageIndicator(this);
    indicator.setViewPager(pager);

    LinearLayout body = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.body);
    body.addView(indicator);
    body.addView(pager);
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not using a jar file, but I had the same error message and fixed it this way in Eclipse:
Right-click on the project, go to Properties > Android, in the Library box, click Add and select the ViewPagerIndicator.

Answer (score 0):

I too was getting the layout inflate error...I know this is pretty old a post, but posting my reply in the hope that anyone stuck up with the same error can resolve it... I followed all the steps that is included in the blog...but the mistake that I did was my library file was in   a very long path (C:/Users//Downloads/Jakewhartan...yada, yada yada/Jakewhartan...../libs) and that was the problem...I shifted it to having a smaller path like F:/workdpace/mylibs and it worked.......

NOW I MAKE A NOTE THAT WINDOWS DOES NOT SUPPORT PROPER LONG PATHS..