# android.view.InflateException error inflating class

Tags: android, xml

I found some problems when implementing [**Jake Wharton**'s ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator).
These are what stated on Logcat:

```
06-19 15:32:02.661: E/AndroidRuntime(692): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.aprian.learn/com.aprian.learn.VPIndicator}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator
```

I have put on the viewpagerindicator library and already put it in build path, but still failed to start the app.

Comment: did you addded to Android->Libraries?

Comment: already add it to Android > Libraries, but still have the same probs, and on the console it stated "could not find com_viewpagerindicator.apk"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the ViewPagerIndicator as a Libarary project as per [Referencing Library Projects](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject). Using it as a .jar-file doesn't work.

Basic steps are:
Add the ViewPagerIndicator as a New Project from existing source and

> To add a reference to a library project, follow these steps:
>
> 1. In the Package Explorer, right-click the dependent project and select Properties.
> 2. In the Properties window, select the "Android" properties group at left and locate the Library properties at right.
> 3. Click Add to open the Project Selection dialog.
> 4. From the list of available library projects, select a project and click OK.
> 5. When the dialog closes, click Apply in the Properties window.
> 6. Click OK to close the Properties window.

If this doesn't work, try Project -> Clean.

Edit: Also see this answer from Jake Wharton : [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8445964/1166813)

Comment: is it correct to put "<com.viewpagerindicator.TitlePageIndicator .../>" on my XML layout? thanks for the response

Comment: then i think the problem lies on my ViewPagerAdapter? my constructor for the adapter ispublic ViewPagerAdapter (Context context) { this.context = context; }

Comment: That's correct. Are you using Eclipse? Tried Clean and/or restarting? Do you have any errors in the viewpagerproject?

Comment: yeah. It works well now, well i dont even know how it works. no change done to it, maybe restarting do the job. thanks